# Creating relationship with name as a variable. (RDBMS to Neo4J migration)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to migrate our current data set to `Neo4J` and was fairly successful so far until I reach this problem. I'm trying to create a set of relationships between 2 node where the name of the relationship is a variable. In my MySQL database, I have Role object which map to a pair of (Resource, Action) so I'm trying to convert it to `Neo4J` with data model such as `(Role)-[Action]->(Resource)`. This is what I have but this doesn't seem like valid syntax:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///roletoresourceaction.csv" AS row
MATCH (role:Role {roleId: row.ROLE_ID})
MATCH (resource:Resource {resourceId: row.RESOURCE_ID})
MATCH (action:Action {actionId: row.ACTION_ID})
MERGE (role)-[r:action.name]->(roleAsResource)
```

Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: This is not supported right now in neo4j :(

Comment: you could create the relationship with a static name and set a "name" property on it just like with the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j 3.x added support for [apoc procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) (which must be installed on the server before they can be used).

With the apoc procedure `apoc.create.relationship`, you *should* be able to do the equivalent of a `MERGE` of *dynamic* relationship types. The Cypher language, by itself, only supports the creation/merging of *static* relationship types.

Hopefully, this works for you:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///roletoresourceaction.csv" AS row
MATCH
  (role:Role {roleId: row.ROLE_ID}),
  (resource:Resource {resourceId: row.RESOURCE_ID}),
  (action:Action {actionId: row.ACTION_ID})
OPTIONAL MATCH (role)-[rel]->(resource)
WITH role, resource, action, COLLECT(TYPE(rel)) AS relTypes
WHERE NOT action.name IN relTypes
CALL apoc.create.relationship(role, action.name, NULL, resource) YIELD newRel
RETURN role, resource, newRel;
```

The `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses verify that the relationship does not already exist before allowing `apoc.create.relationship` to create it.

*ASIDE: I was also hoping to use the `apoc.path.expand` procedure instead of the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause (with some additional changes), but that procedure currently seems to abort the query when it fails to find a match -- even testing the returned path for `NULL` does not help.*

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely help but there are a couple problem I ran into which would be great if you can help explain

1) leaving "USING PERIODIC COMMIT" will fail with this error "The requested operation cannot be performed, because it has to be performed in a transaction. Ensure you are wrapping your operation in the appropriate transaction boilerplate and try again."

2) YIELD newRel will failed with "Unknown procedure output: `newRel`" but changing it to "YIELD rel" fixed the problem and I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///roletoresourceaction.csv" AS row
MATCH
  (role:Role {roleId: row.ROLE_ID}),
  (resource:Resource {resourceId: row.RESOURCE_ID}),
  (action:Action {actionId: row.ACTION_ID})
OPTIONAL MATCH (role)-[rel]->(resource)
WITH role, resource, action, COLLECT(TYPE(rel)) AS relTypes
WHERE NOT action.name IN relTypes
CALL apoc.create.relationship(role, action.name, NULL, resource)      YIELD rel
RETURN role, resource, rel;
```