# Bulk merge of relations in Neo4J using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, bulk

I am trying to create/update distinct relations between two nodes with a single bulk operation in Cypher, leveraging the `MERGE` and `FOREACH` clause.

Right now, I am trying to do it with the following, but it is not syntactically correct:

```
MERGE (u1:Person {id:1})
MERGE (u2:Person {id:3})
FOREACH (score IN [{name:'R1',val:1.0},{name:'R2',val:0.5}]|   
  MERGE (u1)-[r]-(u2)
  WHERE type(r) = score.name
  ON CREATE SET r.weight=score.val,r.created=timestamp(),r.updated=r.created
  ON MATCH SET r.weight=score.val,r.updated=timestamp()
)
```

May you please suggest me a query to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your query is this:

```
MERGE (u1)-[r]-(u2)
WHERE type(r) = score.name
```

Creting relationships without a type is not allowed, nor is it to use a variable name (score.name) for the type of the relationship. I can only suggest two partial solutions:

1) If you are writing the query from some code, insert the name from there. For instance, in PHP: :

```
....
$rels[] = [val => 1.0, name => 'R1'];
foreach ($rels as $rel) {
    $query[] = 'MERGE (u1)-[r:' . '$rel["name"]' . ']-(u2)';
    ON CREATE SET r.weight=score.val, r.created=timestamp(), r.updated=r.created
    ON MATCH SET r.weight=score.val,r.updated=timestamp()
}
....
```

This probably would give an error because of reusing the "r" identifier for the relationship, but that could be avoided making it variable too.

2) A cleaner solution, but maybe not available in your environment, is to use APOC. In Neo4j 3.0+ it´s available to install with many functions for you to use, in particular `apoc.create.relationship.` I am not familiar with this, but [here it´s quite well explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264525/creating-relationship-with-name-as-a-variable-rdbms-to-neo4j-migration).

Anyway here I also leave the [current open issue at neo4j repository](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/340) in case it´s useful.